# MySQL - Order By Parent Position and Child Position

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT process.*
FROM (`process`)
WHERE `company_id` = '1' AND `status` = '1'                                                        
ORDER BY COALESCE(`process`.`parent_id`, `process`.`id`), `process`.`parent_id` IS NOT NULL asc, `process`.`position` asc
```

See SQLFiddie for table, data and query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d50ba/2

The query sorts the sub process correct on its position number.
However I also need the Main process sorted by its position number (both ASC).

**Edit**
The order op IDS should be 7, 1, 16, 41, 42, 6, 40
It should first order all main processes on position by ASC and within each main process order all belonging sub processes on position ASC

It is:

```
╔═════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ parent_id  ║ company_id  ║ department_id  ║       name        ║ user_score  ║ user_comment  ║ ic_score  ║ ic_comment  ║ position  ║ status  ║        date_created        ║
╠═════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  1  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 1    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        2  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:04:03 ║
║ 16  ║ 1          ║          1  ║             3  ║ Sub Process 1, 1  ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        1  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:14:34 ║
║ 41  ║ 1          ║          1  ║             3  ║ Sub Process 4, 1  ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        9  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:06:40 ║
║  6  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 2    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        8  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:08:53 ║
║  7  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 3    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        1  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:09:08 ║
║ 40  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 2    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║       16  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:05:36 ║
║ 42  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 3    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        7  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:14:36 ║
╚═════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Desired output:

```
╔═════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ parent_id  ║ company_id  ║ department_id  ║       name        ║ user_score  ║ user_comment  ║ ic_score  ║ ic_comment  ║ position  ║ status  ║        date_created        ║
╠═════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  7  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 3    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        1  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:09:08 ║
║  1  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 1    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        2  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:04:03 ║
║ 16  ║ 1          ║          1  ║             3  ║ Sub Process 1, 1  ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        1  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:14:34 ║
║ 41  ║ 1          ║          1  ║             3  ║ Sub Process 4, 1  ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        9  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:06:40 ║
║ 42  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 3    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        7  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:14:36 ║
║  6  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 2    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║        8  ║      1  ║ February, 02 2015 21:08:53 ║
║ 40  ║ (null)     ║          1  ║             3  ║ Main Process 2    ║          0  ║ (null)        ║        0  ║ (null)      ║       16  ║      1  ║ February, 09 2015 10:05:36 ║
╚═════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Share desired output, your description is not clear for me

Comment: @lad2025 Please check the Fiddle. The IDs should be as follow 7, 1, 16, 41, 42, 6, 40. It should first ASC all Main processes on position and within the main, all belonging subprocesses should be ASC with position

Comment: Check my edit for correctness

Comment: @lad2025, thanks for the edit. That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but wou will need the position of the parent in the row of the subprocess. To achieve this, you'll need to self join the process table. To achieve the desired sorting I used bitshifting. This will result in a BIGINT, with the first 32 bits reversed for the position of the parent and the later 32 bits reserved for the position of the child. In case of parent rows, their own position is used as the position of for the first 32 bits, the last 32 bits are set to 0.

This results in the the following query:

```
SELECT `process`.*
FROM `process`
LEFT JOIN `process` AS `processParent` ON `processParent`.`id` = `process`.`parent_id`
WHERE `process`.`company_id` = '1' AND `process`.`status` = '1'                                                        
ORDER BY 
    (IF(`process`.`parent_id` IS NULL, `process`.`position`, `processParent`.`position`) << 32)
    + IF(`process`.`parent_id` IS NULL, 0, `process`.`position`) ASC;
```

Edit: Keep in mind this only works if a process is either a parent or a child, but it cannot be both.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment.
So if I understand it correctly the position field should be a BIGINT, but how do I save the position (you mentioned first 32 bits for position parent and last 32 bits for child)

Comment: The query above should give you the desired results. You should not change the position to a BIGINT. But when using bitshifting, MySQL automatically creates a BIGINT for you. The BIGINT has space for 64 bits. So both the position of the parent and child can be stored in this BIGINT. But do not change any of your database, the INT columns are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use bit shifting for this, it seems unnecessarily complex. It seems that you want to order by the parent position first and then the position:

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM `process` p
LEFT JOIN `process` parent 
       ON parent.id = p.parent_id
    WHERE p.company_id = '1' AND p.status = '1'
 ORDER BY COALESCE(parent.position, p.position), 
          parent.position IS NULL DESC,
          p.position
```